# Binding CheckBox IsChecked to Stackpanel Visibility

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to bind the Visibility property of some textboxes in a stackpanel to the IsChecked property of a checkbox in WPF using MVVM. To do so, I have created a property, **IsBoxChecked** as a boolean with a private backing field **_isBoxChecked** which both the textboxes and and checkbox are bound to. When I run the program, the textboxes that have a bound Visibility property are automatically collapsed, regardless of what value I initialize the property to. Also, the checkboxes do not show up checked if I initialize the property to true in the constructor. Here is the code.

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" 
                Margin="10,37" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Always Visible" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Also Always Visible" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Needs to Hide and Unhide" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding IsBoxChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Text" IsChecked="{Binding IsBoxChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

Here is my ViewModel.

```
Public Class NewSpringViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _newWindow As NewView
Private _isBoxChecked As Boolean

Public Sub New()

    _newWindow = New NewView
    _newWindow.DataContext = Me
    _newWindow.Show()

    IsBoxChecked = True

End Sub

Public Property IsBoxChecked As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isBoxChecked
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _isBoxChecked = value
        OnPropertyChanged("IsBoxChecked")
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyName"))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

The checkbox binding to the property works fine it is running. If I set a break point on the setter for the IsBox Checked property, the debugger interrupts if I check or uncheck the box.

Thanks for any help.

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about VB syntax, but should not this

```
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyName"))
```

be changed to

```
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
```

that would explains why there is no notifications. Pass parameter instead of a constant string

also you can directly bind TextBlock Visibility to IsChecked property (reference CheckBox by ElementName)

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" 
        Margin="10,37" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock Text="Always Visible" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Also Always Visible" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Needs to Hide and Unhide" Margin="5" 
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Text" Name="chk" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```